# Multiline cell in Telerik grid (MVC3)

Tags: c#, .net, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Using Telerik MVC3 grid, C#, .Net 2010;

I have a grid in my razor view:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<ProductListItem>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
       columns.Bound(o => o.Current.Name).Sortable(true).Filterable(false).Width(150);
       columns.Bound(o => o.Categories).Sortable(true).Filterable(false).Width(200);
       //other column bindings...
})
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select(Model.GridAjaxRequestAction.ActionName, Model.GridAjaxRequestAction.ControllerName))
.Pageable(settings => settings.Total(Model.TotalRow))
.EnableCustomBinding(true)
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
```

What i want to do is setting Category column of grid as multiline.

There may be many Category for a Product so the Category cells in grid should be like;

```
Category0
Category1
Category2
```

I tried to Join category values with System.NewLine and 
 and assign this values to ProductListItem.Categories property. It does not change. The text is still single line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you @nekno. I came up with this solution in my case. Sorry to not respond in a while.

in view model:

`this.Categories = String.Join("<br>", entity.Categories.Select(o => o.Current.Name));`

in view:
 columns.Bound(o => o.Categories).ClientTemplate("<#= Categories #>")

Answer (score 1):

If it's easy where you tried to do the join with `NewLine`, try `"<br />"` instead of `System.NewLine`.

Otherwise, what is the data type of your `ProductListItem.Categories` property? If it's a `List<String>` or some other `IEnumerable`, you could use a template column instead of a bound column. You use `item` to reference the current `ProductListItem` in the template:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<ProductListItem>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
       columns.Bound(o => o.Current.Name).Sortable(true).Filterable(false).Width(150);
       columns.Template(
            @<text>
                @String.Join("<br />", item.Categories)
            </text>)
            .Sortable(true).Filterable(false).Width(200);
       //other column bindings...
})
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select(Model.GridAjaxRequestAction.ActionName, Model.GridAjaxRequestAction.ControllerName))
.Pageable(settings => settings.Total(Model.TotalRow))
.EnableCustomBinding(true)
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
```

---

Another option might be to make a table in the template column, and leave your `ProductListItem.Categories` as a `List`, e.g., `this.Categories = entity.Categories.Select(o => o.Current.Name).ToList();`

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<ProductListItem>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
           columns.Bound(o => o.Current.Name).Sortable(true).Filterable(false).Width(150);
           columns.Template(
                @<text>
                    <table border=0>
                         @foreach(var category in item.Categories){
                             <tr><td>@category</td></tr>
                         }
                    </table>
                </text>)
                .Sortable(true).Filterable(false).Width(200);
           //other column bindings...
    })
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select(Model.GridAjaxRequestAction.ActionName, Model.GridAjaxRequestAction.ControllerName))
    .Pageable(settings => settings.Total(Model.TotalRow))
    .EnableCustomBinding(true)
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
```

Comment: ProductListItem.Categories property is coming as joined string;     this.Categories = String.Join( "<br />", entity.Categories.Select(o => o.Current.Name)); I tried this and your advice to using Template advice but it still the same :/.

Comment: @berdem - Can you view the HTML source in your browser and paste here what it shows for that table cell with multiple Categories?